Implementing 3d isometric like camera in Unreal BP
Im trying to learn Blueprints and started by implementing my own isometric view from scratch. I have a pawn, with a camera component, the view is supposed to rotate and scroll. I have implemented rotation, by rotating the scene root, but scroll has been more difficult because if I rotate the view, the scroll direction must be calculated based on that rotation and thats what I cant figure out how to do. In other engines, the root object rotation (as a quaternion) can be multiplied by a vector indicating the scroll direction, but here I have tried that and anyway the result is incorrect (the scroll goes diagonally, to the opposite direction, whatever). How can I do this?
